# Muslim Jinn in dunya and jannah

Tags: jinn

Do Muslim jinn have their own ameer ul mumineen and do jihad against kuffar jinn?

Do they get hur al ayn in jannah?

Do they pray behind Muslim man?

Do they do hajj and umrah?

Do they give charity(zakaat)?

Answer (score 0):

All of these Questions are theologically pointless for Muslims. Everything related to jinns are metaphysical and strictly falls into the knowledge of the unseen. So we can only know as much as Allah told us through revelation. None of the things you mentioned are revealed by wahi, so pondering about them is unproductive.

Comment: Ibrahim announced to man jiinn, the rites of hajj